# How to pass updated data from grid to controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my kendo grid the update button does not work after I edit through pop up editor ,"result" is a Ajax call response, since I do not use services I don't need the "read" part that's why I commented it,

**DataSource Initialization:**

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        //read: {
            //    url: result,
            //    dataType: "json"
        //},
        update: {
            url: "/AdminTool/update_grid",
            dataType: "json"
        },                             
        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
            }
        }
    },
    batch: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "DeviceIP",
            fields: {
                DeviceIP: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                Producer: { type: "string" },
                Model: { type: "string" },
                DeviceType: { type: "string" },
                Description: { type: "string" },
                Username: { type: "string" },
                Password: { type: "string" },
                PublicIP: { type: "string" },
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Kendo Grid Initialization:**

```
$("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: result,
    scrollable: false,
    columns: [
       { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceIP' },
       { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor, },
       { field: 'Model', title: 'Model', width: '120px' },
       { field: 'DeviceType', title: 'DeviceType', width: '100px', editor:deviceTypesList },
       { field: 'Description', title: 'Description', width: '100px' },
       { field: 'Username', title: 'Username',width:'120px' },
       { field: 'Password', title: 'Password', width: '100px' },                                          
       { field: 'PublicIP', title: 'PublicIP', width: '120px' },
       { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px" }],
       editable: "popup",
       edit: function() {
               document.getElementsByName("DeviceIP")[0].disabled = true;
       },                          
       editable: "popup"
});
```

**Column Editors:**

```
function ProductNameDropDownEditor(container, options) {             
    $('<input  name="Producer" data-type="string"\">')
       .appendTo(container)
       .kendoDropDownList({
           valuePrimitive: true,
           dataSource: mydata,
           dataTextField: "Text",
           dataValueField: "Text",
    });                                           
}              

function deviceTypesList(container, options) {
    $('<input  name="DeviceType" data-type="string" \">')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: mydata_deviceType,
            dataTextField: "Text",
            dataValueField: "Text",
            //dataValueField: "ProductName",
    });
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult update_grid(TurbineDvce frm)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add update logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**The Model I want to pass**

```
 public class TurbineDvce
{
    public string TurbineId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceIP { get; set; }
    public string Producer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string PublicIP { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: A few notes, you may want to look at [`autoSync`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-autoSync) if you want to call the server automatically any time changes are applied. Alternatively, you can call `sync` manually. You can optionally either use the provided `transport.update` method or alternatively use [AJAX in the `update` function](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.update).

Comment: You can specify the [`data`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.update.data) to be sent with the request. Or optionally look into using [`parameter.map`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap)

Comment: @Sandman thanks but honestly I don't know how should I implement the second one,i don't know if I should write it separately or put in between my kendo grid code,

Comment: The solution you choose will likely depend on the desired behaviour of the update functionality. A row by row update, i.e. `update_grid` called after every row edit or a single update called when all updated rows are to be saved? Update your question with your preference, along with your controller method (`update_grid`) and any other code you feel is necessary to provide more context.

Comment: @Sandman mine is single update in each row,but how should I get the update button work?i should write code for "edit:" ?

Comment: Check this [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/OGuPUr), I think you can use what you have but specify a `parameterMap` function to specify what you want to send to your controller function.

Comment: fine @Sandman but the last question ,in this example its what should I put instead of   var crudServiceBaseUrl = "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service"  ?

Comment: Remove it, just replace the `update.url` with your url ("/AdminTool/update_grid"). You only need to modify your grid initialization code to include the `parameterMap`

Comment: I provided an answer below to encapsulate all the above comment suggestions along with an example for your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `parameterMap` function to specify what data you wish to send to the controller function when editing each individual Kendo Grid row.

You can also specify within the function different methods of returning data based on the operation type.

In your case, an example would be like:

```
transport: {
    update: {
        url:"/AdminTool/update_grid",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
        if(operation !== "read" && data) {
            return kendo.stringify(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in the kendo example there is a part  url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products", I know crudServiceBaseUrl (the url of my controller) but whats the second part(/Product) and my second question is whats   read:  {......   ?    why "read"?

Comment: I have replaced the URL attribute in the example above to use the URL you had in the OP. [`read`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read) is the function used to `GET` the data for the Kendo Grid control from the controller. Full documentation on the `transport` configuration can be found [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport).

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", what do you mean? You updated the question but provided no detail as to the current/expected behavior. Does execution reach the `parameterMap` function, indicating that there may be an issue with the controller function? Additionally, what does `data` contain within the `parameterMap` function? What is your controller function expecting? Update your question with the controller function (`update_grid`) and the structure of the parameters it expects.

Comment: The controller expecting to get a model from my view which is "TurbineDvce" this is the model I use to bind my grid,i also put a break point in my controller(update_grid)but never reached that point after I click on the update button,and in the parameterMap the "data" is the edited data of the grid

Comment: So we can establish that the issue is with the controller function or the structure of the data being passed to the controller function. Update your **question** with the `update_grid` controller function, the structure of your `TurbineDvce` model, and an example of what `data` is being passed from the `parameterMap` function.

Comment: in the Parameter map,according to the model I want to pass,i don't know what should I put in the parameter map,i read the document but still nothing got out it,in the parameter map I should specify what I wana pass to controller,i want to pass the whole grid which is my model,but how should I specify it in the parameter map

Comment: Ensure the spelling is the same as the parameter being sent from the `parameterMap` function e.g. `public ActionResult update_grid(TurbineDvce models)`. Additionally, you may need to reference the position in `options.models` to send, if it is an array e.g. `options.models[0]`.

Comment: In my "DataSource Initialization" up here,i set the id="DeviceIP",which is unique,but still the Update button does not fired,is there in click button I should enable?

Answer (score 0):

your controller action method is expecting parameter name "frm". So it will be like

```
parameterMap: function(options, operations){
  if(operation !== "read" && options{
    return {frm: options}
  }
}
```